# Who published the game Challenge?

Tags: indie-rpg, product-identification

I'm trying to dig up info on a game I played years ago, here's what I think I know:

- The name was most likely Challenge.
- Made use of premade character cards in some way.
- Mark Rein·Hagen may have been the designer, prior to White Wolf.
- Published several months before Vampire: The Masquerade.
- Came in a box, same size as the old D&D basic rules box (the red box).
- Cover art was probably by Joshua Gabriel Timbrook.

Comment: Direct discussion on the appropriateness of this question here: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/should-we-ban-game-system-identification-questions

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a game that is not an RPG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean"The Challenge"? Published 1990.

Here is a link to the details.

[The Challenge](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1682/the-challenge) - listing game Geek

Comment: Wow. Well done. I must have skimmed right over it earlier.